# Why would the order I call SOAP services matter?

Tags: magento2, php, soap

New Magento developer here! I was getting the fatal error: "looks like we got no XML document" when adding a product through SOAP with sets of attributes, pictures, stock etc., after many hours of trying to fix it I finally re-ordered the calls to the SOAP services in the WDSL endpoint, and it started to work! Here's my code that didn't work;

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($magento_service_url."/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogCategoryRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryLinkRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryManagementV1,catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1,configurableProductLinkManagementV1,catalogProductRepositoryV1,catalogProductAttributeRepositoryV1,configurableProductOptionRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryAttributeRepositoryV1,catalogAttributeSetRepositoryV1,catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1",['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'stream_context' => $context]);
```

And here's the line that does work;

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($magento_service_url."/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1,configurableProductLinkManagementV1,catalogProductRepositoryV1,catalogProductAttributeRepositoryV1,configurableProductOptionRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryLinkRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryAttributeRepositoryV1,catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1,catalogAttributeSetRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryManagementV1",['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'stream_context' => $context]);
```

Same calls, different order. The variables have the same values also. Why would the order that I make the calls matter? Hopefully the answers here will also help other people too!

I'm using Magento 2.3.5 on Ubuntu